# How can I get the client IP address with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, socket.io

I've searched the whole SO but I couldn't find my answer. I want to get client IP address with socket io. `v2.0.3`
app.js

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
/// other imports ...

//with or without this line nothing changes
io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.db = db;
  next();
});
require('./sockets')(io, db);
```

sockets.js

```
module.exports = function(io, db) {
   io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      var ip = socket.request.socket.remoteAddress ; // undefined
      //var ip = socket.handshake.headers["x-forwarded-for"]; undefined
      //var ip = socket.handshake.headers["X-Forwarded-For"]; undefined
   });
});
```

so this code does not work:

```
var ip = socket.request.socket.remoteAddress
```

this one does not work eather:

```
var ip = socket.handshake.headers["x-forwarded-for"];
//var ip = socket.handshake.headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
```

with this nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;  
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

is there anyway to get the client IP address with socket.io?

Comment: What do you get when you try using the first one?

Comment: @Wright: `undefined`

Comment: If you could post some of the code to give context on where you're using it, it would help. It works for me.

Comment: @Wright: More codes added. I tried everything (I think) but I can't get the IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed nginx config and the problem solved:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    real_ip_recursive on;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

and in `sockets.js`

```
module.exports = function(io, db) {
   io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        var ip = socket.handshake.headers["x-real-ip"];
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `socket.handshake.address` or `socket.handshake.address.substr(7)`